# How can I remove rows with consecutive zeros?

Tags: r, data.table, data-cleaning

I have a `data.table` in R of time series with columns for the year, location, species, and population count.

I've been trying to find a way to remove the timeseries (or just the years) where there are multiple (three) consecutive population counts of zero.

For example, here is example data to generate in R:

```
dt <- data.table(
  Species = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 6)),
  Location = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
  Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015),
  Count = c(3, 4, 10, 1, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 10, 11, 14, 12, 9)
)
```

With these data, I would expect Species B at Location X would be removed, but the others would be kept.

I've been trying to write my own function but haven't succeeded, I ended up writing a function that would create a `TRUE`/`FALSE` column, using this in a for loop on each location-species combination and then I filtered out time series containing a `TRUE` value from that. But it didn't work and I think I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
consecutive_zeros <- function(dt, Count) {
  Count <- dt$Count
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)-2) { 
  consecutive_zeros <- dt$Count[i] + dt$Count[i+1] + dt$Count[i+2] == 0
  dt$consecutive_zeros[i] <- consecutive_zeros
}
return(dt)
}
```

Comment: So if for a given (Species, Location) if there are three years in a row with 0 you want to remove all observations?

Comment: TEcology, we're all chomping at the bit here ... is it all of `B,X` that you want to remove, just the three consecutive-0 rows, or just the third of three-consecutive-0 rows? It might be clearest if you provide expected output in a static form (similar to how you shared your `dt`).

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This removes any Species/Location for which there are 3 consecutive values of `Count` equal to 0.  rle acting on `Count==0` produces a list with a component logical vector `values` which are `TRUE` for `Count==0`. The list also has a component `lengths` for the corresponding number of consecutive elements and so we can check `lengths[values]` to see if any exceed 2.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  filter(with(rle(Count==0), !any(lengths[values] > 2)), 
    .by = c(Species, Location))
```

giving

```
    Species Location Year Count
 1:       A        X 2010     3
 2:       A        X 2011     4
 3:       A        X 2012    10
 4:       A        X 2013     1
 5:       A        Y 2010     5
 6:       A        Y 2011     0
 7:       C        Y 2010     0
 8:       C        Y 2011    10
 9:       C        Y 2012    11
10:       C        Y 2013    14
11:       C        Y 2014    12
12:       C        Y 2015     9
```

**2)** Since `Count` is non-negative if there are three consecutive 0's then the cumulative sum will equal the cumulative sum 3 positions back so we can check for that.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  filter(!any(diff(cumsum(c(1,1,Count)),3)==0), .by = c(Species, Location))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only the "offending rows", i.e. those 3+ consecutive zeros while keeping the others for that group, I believe a simplistic and kinda hacky way of doing it would be the one below.
Admittedly, it's an ugly piece of code, but I think it's doing what you requested :)

Step 1. Flag rows whose Count = 0 and whose two preceding Counts were also = 0.
Step 2. Go back on the same flag, also flagging those offending rows that came before.
Step 3. Filter out all flagged rows.

```
dt %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  arrange(Species,Year) %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(Count==0&lag(Count)==0&lag(Count,2)==0,1,0), #Step 1
         flag = case_when((lead(flag) == 1 & Count == 0)~1, #Step 2
                          (lead(flag,2) == 1 & Count == 0)~1,
                          .default=flag)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(flag==0) %>% #Step 3
  select(-flag)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 4
   Species Location  Year Count
   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A       X         2010     3
 2 A       Y         2010     5
 3 A       X         2011     4
 4 A       Y         2011     0
 5 A       X         2012    10
 6 A       X         2013     1
 7 B       X         2010     3
 8 B       X         2014     2
 9 B       X         2015     1
10 C       Y         2011    10
11 C       Y         2012    11
12 C       Y         2013    14
13 C       Y         2014    12
14 C       Y         2015     9
```

If you want to remove the group(Species) entirely whenever it has 3 consecutive 0s, then the answer posted right above mine should be the best one instead.

Comment: This does not work correctly, among other reasons it is missing a `Species == C` value (row 13 in the original DT). If you just wanted to remove the offending rows, you would only need `dt %>%  filter(n() <= 2, .by = c(Species, Count, Location))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `frollsum` to sum up when `Count == 0`, then filter out what we don't want.

Starting with:

```r
library(data.table)
dt[, keep := 3 > frollsum(Count == 0, n = 3, fill = 0), by = c("Species", "Location")]
dt
#     Species Location  Year Count   keep
#      <char>   <char> <num> <num> <lgcl>
#  1:       A        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  2:       A        X  2011     4   TRUE
#  3:       A        X  2012    10   TRUE
#  4:       A        X  2013     1   TRUE
#  5:       A        Y  2010     5   TRUE
#  6:       A        Y  2011     0   TRUE
#  7:       B        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  8:       B        X  2011     0   TRUE
#  9:       B        X  2012     0   TRUE
# 10:       B        X  2013     0  FALSE
# 11:       B        X  2014     2   TRUE
# 12:       B        X  2015     1   TRUE
# 13:       C        Y  2010     0   TRUE
# 14:       C        Y  2011    10   TRUE
# 15:       C        Y  2012    11   TRUE
# 16:       C        Y  2013    14   TRUE
# 17:       C        Y  2014    12   TRUE
# 18:       C        Y  2015     9   TRUE
```

It's not clear if you want to remove everything for that species/location

```r
dt[, .SD[all(keep),], by = c("Species", "Location")]
#     Species Location  Year Count   keep
#      <char>   <char> <num> <num> <lgcl>
#  1:       A        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  2:       A        X  2011     4   TRUE
#  3:       A        X  2012    10   TRUE
#  4:       A        X  2013     1   TRUE
#  5:       A        Y  2010     5   TRUE
#  6:       A        Y  2011     0   TRUE
#  7:       C        Y  2010     0   TRUE
#  8:       C        Y  2011    10   TRUE
#  9:       C        Y  2012    11   TRUE
# 10:       C        Y  2013    14   TRUE
# 11:       C        Y  2014    12   TRUE
# 12:       C        Y  2015     9   TRUE
```

or if you want to remove just that observation

```r
dt[(keep),]
#     Species Location  Year Count   keep
#      <char>   <char> <num> <num> <lgcl>
#  1:       A        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  2:       A        X  2011     4   TRUE
#  3:       A        X  2012    10   TRUE
#  4:       A        X  2013     1   TRUE
#  5:       A        Y  2010     5   TRUE
#  6:       A        Y  2011     0   TRUE
#  7:       B        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  8:       B        X  2011     0   TRUE
#  9:       B        X  2012     0   TRUE
# 10:       B        X  2014     2   TRUE
# 11:       B        X  2015     1   TRUE
# 12:       C        Y  2010     0   TRUE
# 13:       C        Y  2011    10   TRUE
# 14:       C        Y  2012    11   TRUE
# 15:       C        Y  2013    14   TRUE
# 16:       C        Y  2014    12   TRUE
# 17:       C        Y  2015     9   TRUE
```

or if you want to remove just the three consecutive zeroes:

```r
dt[dt[, rep(all(keep), .N), by = .(r = rleid(Species, Location, Count == 0))]$V1,]
#     Species Location  Year Count   keep
#      <char>   <char> <num> <num> <lgcl>
#  1:       A        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  2:       A        X  2011     4   TRUE
#  3:       A        X  2012    10   TRUE
#  4:       A        X  2013     1   TRUE
#  5:       A        Y  2010     5   TRUE
#  6:       A        Y  2011     0   TRUE
#  7:       B        X  2010     3   TRUE
#  8:       B        X  2014     2   TRUE
#  9:       B        X  2015     1   TRUE
# 10:       C        Y  2010     0   TRUE
# 11:       C        Y  2011    10   TRUE
# 12:       C        Y  2012    11   TRUE
# 13:       C        Y  2013    14   TRUE
# 14:       C        Y  2014    12   TRUE
# 15:       C        Y  2015     9   TRUE
```

Comment: `frollsum` I totally forgot about that. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick to `data.table` and use `ave` with a custom flagging function.

```
> flag3 <- \(x, len=3) any(with(rle(x), values == TRUE & lengths >= len))
> dt[!ave(Count == 0, Species, Location, FUN=flag3), ]
    Species Location  Year Count
     <char>   <char> <num> <num>
 1:       A        X  2010     3
 2:       A        X  2011     4
 3:       A        X  2012    10
 4:       A        X  2013     1
 5:       A        Y  2010     5
 6:       A        Y  2011     0
 7:       C        Y  2010     0
 8:       C        Y  2011    10
 9:       C        Y  2012    11
10:       C        Y  2013    14
11:       C        Y  2014    12
12:       C        Y  2015     9
```

Note that this groups by Species and Location, you can remove Location if that's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove all rows of a given species and location where there were three 0's in a row, one approach would be to create a temp variable (`three0`) then filter:

Using `dplyr`:

```
dt %>%
  mutate(three0 = n() <= 2, 
         .by = c(Species, Count)) %>%
  filter(!any(!three0), 
         .by = c(Species, Location)) %>% 
  select(-three0)
```

Using `data.table` syntax, the equivalent would be:

```
dt[, three0 := .N <= 2, by = .(Species, Count)][, .SD[all(three0)], by = .(Species, Location)][, !"three0"]
```

Output for both:

```
   Species Location Year Count
 1:       A        X 2010     3
 2:       A        X 2011     4
 3:       A        X 2012    10
 4:       A        X 2013     1
 5:       A        Y 2010     5
 6:       A        Y 2011     0
 7:       C        Y 2010     0
 8:       C        Y 2011    10
 9:       C        Y 2012    11
10:       C        Y 2013    14
11:       C        Y 2014    12
12:       C        Y 2015     9
```

This assumes you want to remove all the observations at a given location, if at any point there were three zeros (which it sounds like in your original question).

If you only want to remove the observations that are affected by three zeros for a given location and species, simply:

```
dt %>% 
    filter(n() <= 2, .by = c(Species, Count, Location))


# or data.table

dt[, .SD[.N <= 2], by = .(Species, Count, Location)]
```

Comment: @s_baldur ha, I know - I initially thought it was pretty straightforward and the more times I read it the more I begin to question what the question was asking. Like a infinite confusion loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in a `dplyr` solution based on my interpretation of the question. Uses `dplyr::lead()` and `data.table::frollsum`.

`lead()` can introduce NA's so those are changed to `FALSE` in this case

```r
# Remove by Species/Location grouping, arranged by Year ascending
library(dplyr)
res <- dt |>
  group_by(Species, Location) |>
  arrange(Year, .by_group = TRUE) |>
  mutate(remove = (frollsum(Count, 3)) == 0) |>
  mutate(remove = remove | lead(remove, 1) | lead(remove, 2)) |>
  mutate(remove = !(remove == FALSE | is.na(remove))) |>
  ungroup()
res
#    Species Location  Year Count remove
#    <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
#  1 A       X         2010     3 FALSE 
#  2 A       X         2011     4 FALSE 
#  3 A       X         2012    10 FALSE 
#  4 A       X         2013     1 FALSE 
#  5 A       Y         2010     5 FALSE 
#  6 A       Y         2011     0 FALSE 
#  7 B       X         2010     3 FALSE 
#  8 B       X         2011     0 TRUE  
#  9 B       X         2012     0 TRUE  
# 10 B       X         2013     0 TRUE  
# 11 B       X         2014     2 FALSE 
# 12 B       X         2015     1 FALSE 
# 13 C       Y         2010     0 FALSE 
# 14 C       Y         2011    10 FALSE 
# 15 C       Y         2012    11 FALSE 
# 16 C       Y         2013    14 FALSE 
# 17 C       Y         2014    12 FALSE 
# 18 C       Y         2015     9 FALSE

# Then remove the TRUE rows
res <- res |> filter(!remove) |> select(-remove)
```